# iOS Login / Sign Out Implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've been attempting to implement a Login / Logout Flow for an iOS app in swift. Here's my storyboard -

[image: Main Storyboard]

In the main view controller (which is the blue screen), I have the following code implemented to detect that if the user is already signed in, then to automatically take them to the table view controller -

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: self)

    }
```

The issue is, that when i Sign In or Login through either one of the green screens, the Table View navigation bar appears different.  The 'Sign Out' button appears properly when the user opens the app and is already logged in, however, logging in or signing in through the green screens, the navigation bar contains a '< Back' button.

Can someone explain how a login / logout flow needs to be implemented in storyboard and programatically in Swift.  I've seen some Objective-C examples out there, but can't seem to find one in Swift.  If anyone has a good example, it would be really helpful.

Comment: so, you are trying to remove the "back" button right?

Comment: in your viewdidload, well if you have one, you have to invoke the "hidesBackButton" property of the UIViewController, this is the way to make this disappear, if this isn't your question, then keep asking or respond to this comment. I would post a code example but there are too many moronic downvoters on the prowl now.

Comment: Thank you, this was one of the issues I was having with the Login flow.  I added 'self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true' to viewDidLoad and it worked great!

Comment: no problem, glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `< Back` button is appearing because you are doing a push segue from the login view controllers to the tab bar controller. A better flow for the app would be to have the tab bar controller be your initial view controller. Then, in its `viewDidAppear` method, check that the user is logged in. If the user isn't logged in, segue modally WITHOUT animation to your login view controller. This will all happen without the user noticing and will allow the storyboard setup you want

Comment: Thank you!  So should my new storyboard flow as follows?  PATH 1: Tab Bar Controller ----> Main View Controller (Blue Screen) --(modal)--> Login Screen --(modal)--> Navigation Controller --(push)--> Table View; PATH 2: Tab Bar Controller ----> Main View Controller (Blue Screen) --(modal)--> Sign Up Screen --(modal)--> Navigation Controller --(push)--> Table View.  Also, how would I prevent the tab bar from showing on the blue screen?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Tab Bar Controller would still have the Table View as its tab item. But it would also have a separate flow like this:  Tab Bar Controller -> (modal) -> Navigation Controller -> (push) -> Main View Controller (Blue Screen). So when the app launches, it will call the Tab Bar Controller's viewWillAppear. In that method, you check if the user is logged in. If the user is logged in, then you stay on the tab bar controller and use the app as normal. If the user is NOT logged in, the you modal segue to the navigation controller and your login screens.

Comment: Thanks.  The issue with this is, on the Table View controller, 'Sign Out' does not work anymore.  If in a Navigation Controller, how do you dismiss the screen so that it goes back to the Blue screen?  This is no issue with a modal (which is what I had before), but with a Push,   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {}); doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated()` is only for dismissing modally presented views. If you want to dismiss a pushed controller, use the `UINavigationController` methods `popToViewControllerAnimated()`, `popToRootViewControllerAnimated()` or `popToViewController(,animated:)`. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) on those methods.

Comment: Ultimately, this was the flow that worked for me.  Also, thanks for helping me fix the Sign Out issue as well @kiethbhunter!

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4**
In LoginViewController's login button action

```
@IBAction func abtn_login(_ sender: Any) {

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialScreenTabBarController") as! InitialScreenTabBarController

        // setting the login status to true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        appDel.window!.rootViewController = centerVC
        appDel.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


}
```

validate login according to your scenario.

In View Controller having the logout button.

```
@IBAction func abtn_logout(_ sender: Any) {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDel.window?.rootViewController = loginVC

}
```

In **AppDelegate**, **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
let userLoginStatus = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

    if(userLoginStatus)
    {
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialScreenTabBarController") as! InitialScreenTabBarController
        window!.rootViewController = centerVC
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: In this case, if we push from rootViewController then the UINavigationController found as nil. So that push operation does not work, after setting up your code. 
So first we get navigationController through:- 
** let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerVC) ** then make as
** window!.rootViewController = navigationController **

Answer (score 2):

You're better off with a setup like the one here. The problem is that your login view resides in a navigation controller as well. Just bring it outside of that. The segue I've place in is a "Show"

Keep in mind that you can embed a Tab Bar controller in a view controller by going up to the menu bar: Editor -> Embed In -> Tab Bar Controller.

Then create a segue to the Tab Bar Controller and you're good to go.

[image]

But what if they're already logged in?

Then you want to save a Boolean flag to `NSUserDefaults` that knows if the user is logged in. Then recall that Bool in `AppDelegate` under the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` similar to this:

```
var isLoggedIn: Bool? // Get From user defaults

        let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as! UIViewController
        let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeNav") as! UIViewController

        if isLoggedIn {
            self.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        }
        else {
            self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Cole, but where would the Tab Bar Controller fit in in this solution?

Comment: Ah shoot, my bad, jumped the gun. Everything will work exactly the same, but instead of embedding "Home" View in a Navigation Controller, it will be a Tab Bar Controller. So it would be `Editor -> Embed In -> Tab Bar Controller`

Comment: The Storyboard setup did not work properly actually.  @keithbhunter solution worked, however, I do not know how to 'Sign Out' now.  Any idea how I can dismiss a View Controller when Sign Out is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

```
  let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Register", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController  = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navForLanding") as! UINavigationController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```