# Logout button in every viewcontroller in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in iOS. I've implemented an login section. Login is working fine. 
But after login, I'm adding a button (logout) manually.
After clicking it, logging out from the app.

Can I make a **header** which will have **Home and Logout** link? So that I won't have to recode same thing in all viewcontroller.

EDIT:- I've achieved this. I'm posting the solution as an answer.

Comment: please see this ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061540/ios-login-sign-out-implementation-in-swift

Comment: @Logic I had already checked that. but it's not same with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an **UILibraryFunction.swift** file.

```
class UILibraryFunction: UIViewController {

var navBar:UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()
var navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "SomeTitle")

var screenWidth:CGFloat = 0
var screenHeight:CGFloat = 0

var NameHeight:CGFloat = 0
var NameWidth:CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height


    NameHeight = screenHeight * 0.09
    NameWidth = screenWidth
    navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: NameWidth, height: NameHeight))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)

    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)

}


//---- Right Bar Button -----
func rightBarButton() {
    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Lge3Generell.Logout(_:)))
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

}

//--- Left Bar Button -----
func leftBarButton() {

    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.GoToHome(_:)))
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton

}

//----- UI Bar Title ----
func setTitle(BarTitle:String) {
    navItem = UINavigationItem(title: BarTitle)
    return navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
}

}
```

Now I call this 3 function in all of my ViewController 's ViewDidLoad like below:-

```
class General: UILibraryFunction {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //-- top bar ------
    setTitle(BarTitle: "Header")
    rightBarButton()
    leftBarButton()

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `UINavigationController` which will contain your view controllers and then add `UIBarButtonItem`s to the navigationController which will persist across all viewControllers

Comment: I'm working with an big app. Will be minimum 100 view. So working with UINavigationController is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a big app as well , this works for me , i am using to to manage logout from any ViewController :

```
       let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! MMLoginViewController

       let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

       appDel.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

Comment: where will I include this code? In AppDelegate? how'll I use it? I'm new in this field..

Comment: use this code in viewcontroller , when you hit signout button , put this code in function of that button.